# How to wait until list is not empty? - Flutter futures

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, future

This is my home screen code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final enterpriseProvider = Provider.of<EnterpriseProvider>(context);
    final resp = enterpriseProvider.indicator;
    final List<IpcData> data = createIpcList(resp);

    print(data);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hola'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: ResultList( formattedData: data )
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  createIpcList(List<List<dynamic>> resp) {

    List<IpcData> ipcList = resp.map((e) => IpcData(e[0], e[1])).toList();
    return ipcList;

  }

}
```

What happens is that the 'resp' value comes from an http request. So when I first call createIpcList(resp); it returns an empty list. The problem here is that the ResultList widget that I use in the Scaffold that´s returned uses that data to build a chart. When I load the app, the chart is blank, as if no data was passed. I noticed that when I make a Hot Restart, it prints an empty list, but some seconds later, it prints the data, as if I called the print again. The problem is that the chart stays blank. I would like to put a condition so if data =! [] it returns me the Scaffold and if not, it returns a loading screen. I know that this can be achieved with Futures, but i don´t know how. I would like to return the Scaffold once I have the data, otherwise my chart will always be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you've to use a **[FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)** widget

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: createIpcList(resp),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ResultList(formattedData: snapshot.data);
    }
);
```

If you want you can show a loading indicator while the data is being fethced from the server.

Comment: `createIpcList` doesn't return a future. You can't use it in a `FutureBuilder` as it is written.